# Determining days between two dates in Excel if a specific criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to count the number of days in a set period, if a certain criteria is met, where:

- `J4` is a departure,
- `F1` is the start of the period;
- `G1` the end date.

If a criteria is `R` in `K4` it needs to give a total, minus one day, if something else it needs to give a blank result in `L4`.

If the date in `J4` is after the end of the month, I need only the days within that month.

So for example: Reporting 1st to 30th June.

- `J4`'s date is 4th of June, their `K4` value is `R`, that should report 3 days in `L4`.
- `j5`'s date is 2nd July, their `K4` value is `R`, that should report 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(EXACT(K4,"R"),IF(J4<G1,J4-F1,G1-F1+1),"")` should work

The `IF()` command takes 3 values.

1. The first is the conditional statement you're evaluating The second
2. Next is the value a cell should be if that conditional statement is true
3. The third value is what the value should be if it's false.`

The `EXACT()` command takes 2 values, and compares them. If the values are the same it is True, otherwise it's False

Comment: Thanks - I just had to change the ; to ,  

How do I get it to count dates only during the 1st-30th period?

Comment: What do you mean? Like don't count for anything that's more than 30 days?

Comment: That's right.  Even though it may be say, 46 days, I only need the days that fall inside the current accounting period (in this example, 1st to 30th June)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that in your original question. I've updated the answer for you, it will now check if the if the date is within the period

Comment: Oops.  Now it's coming up as a negative number! i.e. -52 days

Comment: Can you post the cells and their values that cause that? Is the formula the exact same? It should be `J4<G1` not J`4>G1`

Comment: =IF(EXACT(K5,"R"),IF(J5<G1,J5-F1,G1-J5),"")

The end date on THAT one is 21/8 so it's outside the reporting month

Comment: What are the values of the individual cells for that you're referencing? K5, J5, etc

Comment: K5 R, J5 21/08/14, G1 30/06/2014, F1 01/06/2014

Comment: Going by the last day in the month.  So if their end date is after 30th June it just counts the days anyway.

Comment: 30 days.  1st of June to 30th June.

Comment: It came up "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Comment: I think you forgot a `)` somewhere in there

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
=IF(K4="R",IF(J4>EOMONTH(G1,0),DAY(G1),DAY(J4)-1),"")
```